# Failed an audit on Review First Posts - answer was correct

Tags: discussion, review-audits, first-post-review

While reviewing first posts, I was presented with this one:

[I can't do android things image after console option is used to build a new image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185353/i-cant-do-android-things-image-after-console-option-is-used-to-build-a-new-imag)

The answer I was asked to judge was this (sorry, answer is not visible to me, so I have to paste it verbatim):

> Your SD card needs to be class 10. Did you verify that?

I scrolled down to see the original post, where I noticed this edit at the bottom...

> SOLVED w I change sd card to class 10 sd

Naturally I thought "hey, the answer is right, and awaaaay we go". Alas, no dice.

Was this test some sort of automatically chosen example blind to the subject at hand, was I wrong in saying yes to the approval, or does the example maybe fall into a grey area?

Comment: [This is the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17657827). Frankly, I don't think it's a very good audit. Just because it's a rhetorical question doesn't mean it is not an answer.

Comment: Looked through your recent reviewing history with an eye towards lifting your ban. Maybe something I could be talked into doing, but I do notice  you aren't ***editing*** enough. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17656728), that question *desperately* needs formatting improvement. [The previous review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17656846) is a fine question, but needs to be edited to remove all of the noise that creates a big wall of text. Also, dunno what happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17656482). That's not OK.

Comment: [This question is also not OK](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17656731), and almost certainly needed a "recommend closure" flag for being unclear, too broad, or even lacking an MCVE. Please do use *all* of the options available to you when reviewing. It's not just a choice of "Looks OK" or "Delete". Editing is often a good choice for borderline questions, and where you can't edit it into shape yourself, flagging to close is quite appropriate.

Comment: Uh, okay, well I can respond to those individual cases and give my reasoning (e.g. the Excel example, not sure how you make a MCVE for that without having a downloadable file), but that's just going to be noisy. Maybe I should be editing more, but I feel that too much editing can unwittingly change the character of the question or introduce bugs in the code. If I'm banned, so be it, not everyone is cut out for this kind of thing

Comment: Yeah, you need to be really careful when editing code (and probably abstain altogether if you're not an expert in the tech) to keep from introducing bugs. For English, that's not a problem. If you can improve the clarity of the question by rewriting it or removing irrelevant bits, then you are encouraged to do so. The site is collaboratively edited for precisely this reason; it's one of our biggest features. On the other hand, it's true not everyone is cut out for reviewing. Never forget the "Skip" option. If it looks like something needs editing, but you don't feel comfortable doing it, Skip!

Comment: I tend to do a lot of skipping, mostly over languages I don't know, or for questions where I'm not sure they're good or not. I guess I've not been totally on the ball with some of these calls, but I keep seeing Triage and First Posts in the red lately, so try to do my bit to help. I'm happy to hang up my gloves if that's the decision, but also happy to learn how to do things better.

Comment: I'm certainly not trying to discourage you from reviewing, much less asking you to stop. All bans are *temporary*, with the idea being to give you a chance to reflect on how you've been reviewing and how you can improve. Asking on Meta is exactly what you're supposed to do if you have a question or don't understand how you should have acted differently. I'm trying to give some advice.

Comment: Thanks Cody, I hear you. Look, I'm on holidays for the next few days, then training up staff for a week after that, so by then the ban will have lifted and I will have had time to reflect. Thanks for your comments, it's helped clarify the role of reviewer for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That answer is converted to a comment, you can see it as the last comment on the question

> Your SD card needs to be class 10. Did you verify that? – Bruno Zaranza [Oct 12 at 1:53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185353/i-cant-do-android-things-image-after-console-option-is-used-to-build-a-new-imag#comment80350035_46185353)

You proceeded because OP commented it is working for him. But it didn't make an answer good. That answer is stating a requirement and asks the OP for clarification. So it doesn't worth keeping.

#### The main issue here is that the question itself is off topic here.

If the problem is solved by changing sd card to class 10, then it is related to Hardware. And the question is off topic in Stack Overflow.

They may able to get help on [Rasberry Pi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).